# Codeigniter Email, Html not working over TLS Encryption

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have a running CodeIgniter email configuration using office 365 SMTP TLS Encryption.
But my HTML message was broken

```
$email_message = [
            'name' => "USERNAME",
            'code' => "03940",
        ];

        $message = $this->load->view('emails/code_email', $email_message, true);

        $this->load->library('email');

        $config["protocol"] = "smtp";
        $config["smtp_host"] = "smtp.office365.com";
        $config["smtp_port"] = "587";
        $config[ "smtp_crypto"] = "tls";
        $config["smtp_timeout"] = "7";
        $config["smtp_user"] = "some@email.com";
        $config["smtp_pass"] = "someemailpassword";
        $config["charset"] = "utf-8";
        $config["newline"] = "\r\n";
        $config["mailtype"] = "html"; // or text
        $config["validation"] = true;

        $this->email->initialize($config);
        $this->email->set_newline("\r\n");

        $this->email->from('some@email.com', 'Some Email');
        $this->email->to('user@email.com');
        $this->email->subject('Test Lang');
        $this->email->message($message);

        if ($this->email->send()) {
            echo 'OKS';
        } else {
            echo $this->email->print_debugger();
        }
```

This is what I got:

[email i got](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6Nr6n.png)

This what I expected to show:

[email expected](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mwmSg.png)

Comment: change `$config["newline"] = "\r\n";` to `$config["newline"] = "rn";`

Comment: the html of the email is probably invalid

Comment: @fmsthird i tried what you said but i get the same output.

Comment: @tim i check my code it seem's okay.

Comment: @BossMaltik can you include your `$message` content

Comment: @BossMaltik add this `$config["crlf"] = "\r\n";` before `$config["newline"] = "\r\n";`